# Software to create a map of teammates in the city and moves during the week

Tags: data-visualization, maps, animation

I organize a week of events in my city, and I have a team of 10 persons that will be at different places at differents times during the week.

I'd like to build a map in which each teammate enter a date / time and his position, then you can "play" the time to see markers move.

I tried with Google Maps but it's difficult to handle the "time" variable:  I tried with "one layer per day", but it's not convenient to "play" the time and I cannot visualize intraday moves.

What software can do this?

PS : If the map is collaborative it's better : each teammate would plan it's positions along the week and update himself if there is a change.

Comment: What OS should it run on? What's your price limit (in case it matters)?

Comment: Does the map have to be accessible online, or would a desktop/offline software work? If it has to be a web app, hosted (like Google Maps) or self-hosted on your own server?

Comment: I need an online service, yes, like google map. Not with expensive annual license. We would not pay much than tens of dollars per map or per month.

Comment: If the map is collaborative it's better : each teammate would plan it's positions along the week and update himself if there is a change.

Comment: @JulienD Please edit your Question with further info rather than post as comments.